# What´s wrong with my Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I dont know whats wrong with my Terminal that i see like this:

[image]

see that it appears -bash-3.2$, instead of:

[image]

Apologize my english, im from Argentina

Comment: Wrong site. This site is for programming questions. You're looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: im sorry, i didnt know that

Comment: The [help] for every [se] site has information about the guidelines for that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to override the PS1 variable to change the prompt.

Set your PS1 to "Macbook:~ \u$" like this-

```
PS1="Macbook:~ \u$"
```

If you want your host name to be printed instead of "Macbook" use \H.

This [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) will give you more info.